# Post image on facebook using FBSDK 4.x for iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

For the new `Facebook SDK 4.x (4.1) for iOS` had new changes with the frameworks . It includes 3 different framework as like

- Core
- Sharing
- Login.

To share any image I used `FBSDKSharePhoto` Class. But it has method

```
[FBSDKSharePhoto photoWithImage:(*UIImage) userGenerated:(BOOL)]
```

I want to add caption with the image as string and text. can Anyone help me for this so I can post caption with the image using  FB's new sdk.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Did you get any solutions using FBSDK?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assign your Caption String to  caption Key value

**@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *caption;**

Try This :

```
 FBSDKSharePhoto *photo = [[FBSDKSharePhoto alloc] init];
      photo.image = image;
      photo.userGenerated = YES;
    photo.caption = @"Add Your caption";
      FBSDKSharePhotoContent *content = [[FBSDKSharePhotoContent alloc] init];
      content.photos = @[photo];
    [FBSDKShareDialog showFromViewController:self
                                 withContent:content
                                    delegate:nil];
```

Comment: Nice answer, by the time i converted my code from swift to obj-c i saw your post. +1

Comment: It shows dialog and after adding text posted on facebook. but the added caption is not showing on the post.... please check

Comment: hello @Esha i am facing same issue as like you, did you get any solution then please let me know.

Answer (score 7):

As @NANNAV posted it will work, but if you want to share silently with out any FB Dialog screen then use "shareWithContent" as below, but you need to submit your Facebook app for review.

**Code in Obj-c**

```
FBSDKSharePhoto *sharePhoto = [[FBSDKSharePhoto alloc] init];
sharePhoto.caption = @"Test Caption";
sharePhoto.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"BGI.jpg"];

FBSDKSharePhotoContent *content = [[FBSDKSharePhotoContent alloc] init];
content.photos = @[sharePhoto];

[FBSDKShareAPI shareWithContent:content delegate:self];
```

**Code in Swift**

```
var sharePhoto = FBSDKSharePhoto()
sharePhoto.caption = "Test"
sharePhoto.image = UIImage(named: "BGI.jpg")

var content = FBSDKSharePhotoContent()
content.photos = [sharePhoto]

FBSDKShareAPI.shareWithContent(content, delegate: self)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this need extended permission as well the permission from the fb app.

Comment: @Esha yes you need publishPermissions : "publish_actions" in order to make it work.

Comment: And for this new SDK I had one more problem as unable to get Publish_action permission. It always goes into canceled block. although  openUrl, active app and launch option methods are set.

Comment: You can get the publish and other type of permissions as you create your facebook app and try to review your permissions on that app once your permissions are Granted by facebook team you can you that app id in your ios app..keep coding

Comment: I am using QA version of app, but still its asking like
 [FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] is missing publish_actions permissions

Comment: How to attach location(placeID) with content in swift?

Answer (score 2):

Add the below code to share text to facebook using Facebook SDK 4.x

```
 FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection  =[[FBSDKGraphRequestConnection alloc]init];

NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Your_message_here_to_share_FB", @"message",
                               nil];
FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me/feed" parameters:params HTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[connection addRequest:request completionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
    if(error){
           NSLog(@"Failed to share");
        }
    else{
           NSLog(@"Updated successfully");

        }

}];
```

*Add below code to share photo.

```
FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection  =[[FBSDKGraphRequestConnection alloc]init];

NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: image, @"picture",
                               @"Your_text_here",@"message",
                               nil];

FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me/photos" parameters:params HTTPMethod:@"POST"];

[connection addRequest:request completionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

    if(result)
    {
        NSLog(@"Posting the image is success, the result is%@",result);
    }
    else if(error)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error occured while posting image %@",error);
    }
}];

[connection start];
```

Comment: Must check for publish_action permission before posting with graph